# Laravel 5 Eloquent ORM - Many to Many through Many to Many

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I'm working on a rather complex Users system that requires the ability to grant access privileges to either individuals or entire groups. For example, you could grant Jane Doe access to moderate the Message Board, or all users of the Communications Group to send emails, moderate the message board, and post events (all users assigned to the group are granted access to those privileges when added).

Rather than strictly track individual privileges for each user, I want to grant access to a feature first based on whether or not the user belongs to a group containing that privilege. If they don't, I then want to check to see if they are granted individual access (`privilege_user` pivot table).

Basically, I want something like this:

```
// 1 = Message Board Moderator
// See if any of the user's groups contain this privilege -
$hasAccess = Auth::user()->groups->privileges->contains(1);
```

Here is my table structure:

**Users**

```
| Field          | Type             | Null | Key | Default             | Extra          |
+----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| id             | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment |
| username       | varchar(80)      | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| email          | varchar(120)     | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| first_name     | varchar(20)      | NO   | MUL | NULL                |                |
| last_name      | varchar(45)      | NO   | MUL | NULL                |                |
| password       | varchar(140)     | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| active         | tinyint(1)       | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| remember_token | varchar(100)     | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| last_login     | timestamp        | YES  |     | NULL                |                |
| last_login_ip  | varchar(45)      | YES  |     | NULL                |                |                
| updated_at     | timestamp        | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                |
| created_at     | timestamp        | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                |
| deleted_at     | timestamp        | YES  |     | NULL                |                |
+----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
```

**Groups** (table: user_groups)

```
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| Field       | Type             | Null | Key | Default             | Extra          |
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| id          | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment |
| name        | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| slug        | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| description | text             | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| created_at  | timestamp        | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                |
| updated_at  | timestamp        | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                |
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
```

**User Groups Pivot** (table: user_user_group)

```
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field         | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| user_id       | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| user_group_id | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

**Privileges** (table: privleges)

```
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name  | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| slug  | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

**Privileges User Group Pivot** (table: privilege_user_group)

```
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field         | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| privilege_id  | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| user_group_id | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Comment: What is your question? It's a simple role/permissions system but I don't know what you're asking for.

Comment: Thought I was fairly clear but here's another way of saying it. A user can belong to many Groups. A Group can have many Privileges. I need to see if a particular user belongs to a group that has a particular Privilege, a Group can have many Privileges. So, "Does this User have access to this Privilege through one of their Groups, if any?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was disappointed that nobody chimed in here on SO but fortunately I was able to find some great help at Laracasts.com.

I went with [Zizaco/entrust](https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust/tree/laravel-5), which does exactly what I was describing. The only part lacking is answering the question "does this User have a Permission" without the user being assigned to a Group, but that is easy to accomplish with Eloquent. What entrust does do is answer the question "Does this User have access to this Permission through a Group?" And that's what I was after.